# How to find repeating sub-pattern in path traversing graph neo4j

Tags: node.js, algorithm, rest, graph, neo4j

To start things off, I'm using a Node server to hit the REST API, is it possible to access the Java [CostEvaluator Interface](http://api.neo4j.org/1.6.1/org/neo4j/graphalgo/CostEvaluator.html) using Cypher or the REST API? I'm unwilling to write this in Java (honesty, lol).

I've reviewed the docs pretty extensively, and I can't even find a place where cypher's `allShortestPaths` is documented. It'd be wonderful to know what arguments that could take, so if you know where i can read about those, please let me know in comments.

Moving on:

The graph is formed of patterns such as this: `sub_path = (start:STEPNODE)<-[cost:COST_REL {cost}]-(axis_node:AXISNODE)-[:TRANSIT_TO]->(end:STEPNODE)`. There are only 14 `(:STEPNODE)`, which helps constrain things a bit... but there may be many thousands of `(:AXISNODE)`s. Each `(:AXISNODE)` has a unique relationship with any `(:STEPNODE)` pair.

`sub_path` is a repeating pattern, in pseudo:`(node1:STEPNODE)-{sub_path_1_to_2 {cost}}-(node2:STEPNODE)-{sub_path_2_to_3 {cost}}-(node3:STEPNODE)-{sub_path_3_to_4 {cost}}-(node4:STEPNODE)`, but `(node1:STEPNODE)-{sub_path_1_to_4 {cost}}-(node4:STEPNODE)` may also exist.

Each sub path has an important `{cost}` which is measured on the `[COST_REL]` relationship. I'd like to find the least expensive path from `(begin:STEPNODE)-[sub_path*1..5]->(end:STEPNODE)` where the total cost is the sum of all `{cost}`. I see this as being a matter of finding the sum of `sub_path.cost`, but I haven't yet found a strategy that supports passing a `sub_path` or `cost` argument to allShortestPaths() or any similar function with Cypher. On the [Algo Endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html) of the API, there's an argument for `dijkstra` with a `cost_property` but this endpoint doesn't seem to support passing a `sub_path` argument.

I'm find with a sub-optimal solution. But I would really like to avoid making more than a few API calls to find a cheap route through the

Comment: Perhaps you can add a picture that depicts your sub-paths. I think for this you'll have to go with a server extension. If you can write Java it would be a no-brainer. At some point it will be possible with Cypher and UDFs but not in the near future.

Comment: In that Java extension you can use Dijkstra or A* with cost evaluators to compute your sub-paths and apply these algorithms recursively.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks, @MichaelHunger for the super fast response.